# Nginx 502 - [error] 11679#0: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1

Tags: configuration, nginx

I'm doing a local installation of an existing project and facing some issues to make it work.

I keep getting **502 Bad Gateway - nginx **, when I check the error log, I see that the domain is being multiplied for some reason.

```
021/12/27 15:27:25 [error] 11679#0: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: project.local, request: "GET /project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/project.local/lv/
```

I already tried to add all possible configs to nginx, to increase its capacity, here is my current one:

```
#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65000;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
client_header_timeout 3000;
client_body_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
client_max_body_size 32m;
client_header_buffer_size 64k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
```

I tried all top 10 approaches found here and StackOverflow to similar problems, but nothing is working.

I would appreciate it if someone more experienced could help me out on this one, 2 days stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are proxying to your magento host i.e.

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://magento_servers;
    ...
  }
```

This configuration should resolve the problem

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Comment: No, not proxying.